# Hardware ID on Device Manager

Tags: windows-7, drivers, sound-card, device-manager

HardwareID: (Open Start, type devmgmt.msc and press enter. Double click a device. Choose the Details tab and then the Hardware Ids from the drop-down.)

**I want, from HardwareID, discover the the manufacturer and model of a device.**

By example, I'm trying install that device:

```
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4370&SUBSYS_3091103C&REV_02  
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4370&SUBSYS_3091103C  
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4370&CC_040100  
PCI\VEN_1002&DEV_4370&CC_0401
```

Sometimes Windows7 show it as "Conexant AC-Link Audio", but I cannot install several driver versions that I've downloaded from web.

Thank you very much any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an interesting article about just that: [link](http://www.technibble.com/pcidatabase-repair-tool-of-the-week/)

There are also various tools that will discover what the device is and which drivers you need.
(I often use Everest, but it's a shareware and not a tool that is specifically for that purpose, there are others I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

download and run **[SIW](http://www.gtopala.com/download/siw.exe)**

click on **PCI** in the **Hardware** section of the navigation pane. then highlight the device in question and SIW will provide Hardware and Compatible IDs

having said that, did you run Windows Update? this should be your first stop on the quest for Windows 7 device drivers.